# How to build a custom terminal in linux?

Tags: linux, terminal

I want to build a custom linux terminal that would deal with api's of certain websites directly from the terminal . Yes I know , Curl can do that too . But lets say the content of the website are now in your computer and the website is offline . Thus using this terminal I would like to access those contents and make changes to them . 
Again this also can be done using the linux terminal , but I would like this terminal to be very specific and have its own syntax and semantics .

For example , the ruby terminal from which you can run various ruby code without actually compiling them .

Thus what books should I read and how should I go about it in building this ?

Comment: I think googlecl is a good reference point for what you're looking to do [ http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/ ].

Answer (score 0):

Making changes on a site (like this site) not only involves some HTML content, but also a lot of code that runs on web server side. This is what you can't replicate with `curl` and possibly with any reasonably small amount of work at all.

'Terminal' is probably a wrong word; it seems that you just want a command-line app, as opposed to a GUI or Web app.

Please try to describe a more specific scenario. Your question is currently too vague.

Comment: Lets say the wiki project is taken offline . All the wikipages are taken offline . If I come up with a terminal , that would actually communicate with the database with the api that would also be produced by me so as to access the wiki pages and also deal with creation of wiki-pages .

Comment: Then your best bet is to install locally roughly the same software that the site in question uses, including databases, web frontends, etc. For open-source and otherwise available software this should be easy or at least doable.  Copy original site's data periodically; e.g. Wikipedia just provides ready-made data bundles for mirroring. Use local web interfaces, and/or develop custom interfaces, and don't hit the remote site.

Answer (score 0):

I liked ["Kernel projects for Linux" by Gary Nutt](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201612437).  It will help you in learning the design of a shell, and how the shell interacts with the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe to configure web server to respond to local HTTP queries and use console based web browser like elinks or lynx